# Modeling array assignment in Z3

Tags: z3

I'm working on a project for program verification. I have the following statement to be modeled in Z3:

```
temp = a[i];
a[i] = a[j];
a[j] = temp;
```

All the variables are of integer type. Would someone give me some hints on how to build constraints to model the above statements?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general "recipe".

We represent array updates using `(store a i v)`. The result is a new array equal to `a`, but at position `i` contains the value `v`.
An array access `a[i]` should be encoded as `(select a i)`. 
Assignments such as `i = i + 1` are usually encoded by creating Z3 variables that represent the value of `i` before and after the assignment. That is, we would encode it as `(= i1 (+ i0 1))`.
Keep in mind that the formula `(= i (+ i 1))` is equivalent to `false`.

Here is the example above encode in SMT 2.0 format.

http://www.rise4fun.com/Z3/G5Zk

Here is the script found in the link above.

```
(declare-const a0 (Array Int Int))
(declare-const a1 (Array Int Int))
(declare-const a2 (Array Int Int))
(declare-const temp0 Int)
(declare-const temp1 Int)
(declare-const i0 Int)
(declare-const j0 Int)

(assert (= temp0 (select a0 i0)))
(assert (= a1 (store a0 i0 (select a0 j0))))
(assert (= a2 (store a1 j0 temp0)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```